# Redux Toolkit Query: Error: Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IGetSpaceQueryParams | unique symbol'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I am hoping to fix an error I am getting while calling my hook from RTK Query. I am making a simple GET request and sending it a string for an ID. However, something is off with the interfaces or the way I am making my query and receiving a type error. How can I fix this? I am not sure where the 'unique symbol' part is coming from as well.

Where I call the hook:

```js
const { myId } = useSRZId();
const {
  data: space,
  isLoading: spaceLoading
} = useGetSpaceQuery(myId); // <---error here on myId
```

> `Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IGetSpaceQueryParams | unique symbol'.`

Where I get the ID:

```js
export const useSRZId = (): { myId?: string; } => {
  const myId = query.get(EQueryParam.SID) || undefined;
  return { myId };
};
```

My query:

```js
getSpace: builder.query<IGetSpaceQueryResponse, IGetSpaceQueryParams>({
   query: ({ myeId }: IGetSpaceQueryParams) => ({
     url: `/spaces/${myId}`,
     method: 'GET'
   }),
}),

export interface IGetSpaceQueryParams {
  myId: string;
}

export interface IPutSpaceQueryParams {
  myId: string;
  space: Partial<ISpace>;
}
```

Comment: your types don't match. try ```useGetSpaceQuery({myId} as IGetSpaceQueryParams)```.
because myId is a string while IGetSpaceQueryParams is an interface with myId key

Answer (score 1):

Your query says that the argument is an **object** which has a property `myId`.

```
export interface IGetSpaceQueryParams {
  myId: string;
}
```

But here, you are calling it with a **string**, not an `object`.

```
useGetSpaceQuery(myId);
```

If you want to pass the string directly as the argument, then you need to modify your query definition like so:

```
getSpace: builder.query<IGetSpaceQueryResponse, string>({
   query: (myId: string) => ({
     url: `/spaces/${myId}`,
     method: 'GET'
   }),
}),
```

You can handle cases where the `myId` variable might be `undefined` by skipping the query.

```
import { skipToken } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query';
```

```
useGetSpaceQuery(myId || skipToken);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const myId = query.get(EQueryParam.SID) || undefined;
```

The problem lies here, you're setting myId as possibly undefined, when it's type does not allow for that.

The myId type has to match the query param type.